# Python Pandas : Find nth largest and count in case of tie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In a pandas `DataFrame`, I want to find the nth largest value (row wise, not column wise) and then also find, if there are ties. I am interested in finding top 3 largest and ties. Note, there are more than 3 columns in actual problem,
e.g. if the data frame looks like this:

```
    A B C
0   1 2 2
1   3 4 3
2   1 2 3
```

I want to know the nth largest values and if there were ties, so:

- row 0 - 1st largest is 2 with a tie, 1 2nd largest, no third largest,
- row 1 - 1st largest is 4, 3 2nd largest with a tie, no third largest,
- row 2 - 1st largest 3, 2nd largest 2, 3rd largest 1.

Expected output as requested:

```
   A  B  C  max1  max2  max3  tie1  tie2  tie3
0  1  2  2     2     1   NaN     1     0   NaN
1  3  4  3     4     3   NaN     0     1   NaN
2  1  2  3     3     2   1.0     0     0   0.0
```

Comment: Why is 4 not mentioned in row 1 and think you've got your 1 and 3 swapped in your row 2 example...

Comment: I've edited my question,thanks for pointing out

Comment: Can you add expected output? It is DataFrame?

Comment: I'd like to take further action if its a tie. So at this stage if I can get these values as dataframe columns that would be good.

Comment: @PriyankaJ - OK, can you add expected output `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#top N values
N = 3
#reshape to MultiIndex Series and counts values per index, sorting 
df1 = (df.stack()
         .groupby(level=0).value_counts()
         .sort_index(ascending=[True, False])
         .reset_index(level=1))
#counter level to MultiIndex for new columns names
s = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)
df1 = df1.set_index(s, append=True)
#filter topN rows
df1 = df1[s.le(N).values]
df1.columns=['max','tie']
#subtract 1 for correct tie
df1['tie'] -= 1
#reshape to df with MultiIndex
df1 = df1.unstack()
#flatten columns names
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
#add to original
df2 = df.join(df1)
print (df2)
   A  B  C  max1  max2  max3  tie1  tie2  tie3
0  1  2  2   2.0   1.0   NaN   1.0   0.0   NaN
1  3  4  3   4.0   3.0   NaN   0.0   1.0   NaN
2  1  2  3   3.0   2.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: there is no way to get the max and then get count of columns that match max value?

Comment: this gives me the expected output, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without transpose . With transpose , essentially this means iterating over each row of dataframe which I don't want

Comment: @PriyankaJ - You are absolutely rigth, previous solution was not very pythonic, so answer was changed.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    l = df.loc[0].tolist()
    d = {key: l.count(key) for key in l}
```

The dictionary now contains the values and how many times it has been repeated in the row. You can then print the top-n values of the dictionary easily.